# How to save ninja build output without loosing the compressed format of output

Tags: tee, ninja, unicode-escapes

I tride to duplicate the output of the `ninja` build system to the separate file but I want to save original campresed look of the `ninja` output.

If I `tee` ninja (`ninja all | tee -a someFile`) I get wall of text [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E8Bk.png)
Instead of updating one line.

If there is a better way to duplicate the output of `ninja` to file without loosing the compress formatig of output please let me know!

UPD: I find out that `ninja` update lines with `[K` `escape sequence` (erasing the line) and after capturing or rederecting `ninga` output it vanishing. If some body know how to allowed system to capture all tipy of escape sequence, it will solve my problem

Comment: It's better to clearly mention what is the formatting diff you want to avoid.

Comment: @Kamath I want to save the compressed output of `ninja`, when you build the project by ``ninja progress showed in one line that is updating and it nice, but when I use `tee` it printing progress as the wall of text and I want to avoid this.